# Mediaquery not working for iPhone

Tags: css, media-queries

I am building a website on a template which has some media-queries. Only the lowest max-width is 479, which is not for iPhone if I'm correct (and if it is, it's not working).

I can't really simulate the screen of an iPhone by resizing my browser so it's hard to test, since the only iPhone I got to test on is in use a lot of the time.

Looking at another template which does have iPhone support, I took the mediaquery from there, but it's not working.

The code that I added:

```
@media (max-width: 359px) {
    .smaller{
        font-size: 10px;    
    }
}
```

This should work right?

Anybody know the correct media-query? And maybe something to test the iPhone responsive version without using an iPhone?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue in your media query is in the "max-width", which refers to the target display area.

You should use "min-device-width" / "max-device-width" instead, which refers to the device's rendering area.

Regarding the testing iPhone specific styles without using the actual device - here are some browser based examples you might want to check out:

- Google Chrome developer tools device mode (https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/device-mode)
- Firefox Responsive Design View (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Responsive_Design_View)

Comment: Alright, thank you, didn't know Firefox had that feature. I'll look into it.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this. Below link will help you to write your media queries for iPhone.

http://stephen.io/mediaqueries/

```
iPhone 5 Media Queries

iPhone 5 in portrait & landscape

@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 568px) { /* STYLES GO HERE */}

iPhone 5 in landscape

@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 568px) 
and (orientation : landscape) { /* STYLES GO HERE */}

iPhone 5 in portrait

@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 568px) 
and (orientation : portrait) { /* STYLES GO HERE */ }
```